# SCEP routing using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, router, routing

Does anyone know about SCEP routing table on linux? I would like to know if it is possible using software routing to scep requests go to another machine then usually goes using 443 or 80?

tks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting you right, you have an HTTP server running on your machine that is receiving SCEP requests as well as regular HTTP requests.  You want to forward the SCEP requests to another server and leave the HTTP requests alone.  Is that right?

The right place to do this is in the HTTP server config, not in the packet filter.  `iptables` deals best with individual packets, and we're talking about parsing a TCP stream (an HTTP stream, even), which is what the webserver does best.

I don't know much about SCEP, but it seems to me that an even better thing to do would be to have the SCEP requests go to the correct server in the first place.  Is there a DNS or other announcement that you could change somewhere?  Could you specify a different port number for SCEP than for HTTP?